# TFS restoration-based move

Tags: tfs, migration, upgrade

When moving TFS from one machine to another by restoring it to new hardware (restoration-based move), the name of the old machine gets listed under the Application Tiers tab and is visible if the "Filter out machines that have not connected in more than 3 days" checkbox is unchecked.

To upgrade hardware and TFS version in one move:

- Is it necessary to always keep the same machine name?
- Does TFS support machine name change during restoration-based moves? (this will be in the case that we have Machine A and Machine B. Machine A is the old production tier and Machine B is the new one, where the databases will be moved and upgraded.)
- Does the name machine change have any effect if TFS has an alias name for the public URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should confirm one thing, do you need to use the original hardware and TFS deployment or not.

You perform a **move** when you plan to discontinue use of the original hardware and TFS deployment. You perform a clone when you intend to continue using the original TFS instance.

*Please take a look at [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015)*

If you just [restored an application-tier server](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-application-tier-server), for restoring an application-tier server, the name of the old application-tier server remains there is expected (See the end of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-application-tier-server).).

> **Note:** The name of the old application-tier server will still appear in
>   the list of application-tier servers in the administration console for
>   Team Foundation. If you select the Filter out machines that have not
>   connected in more than 3 days check box, the old server will disappear
>   from the list within three days.

So, to avoid showing the old App Tier machine name you need to follow the steps in above tutorial-- Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another.

> **Moreover:** You must install but not configure TFS on the new data-tier
>   server, and then use the restore function in the Scheduled Backups
>   node

Comment: @ PatrickLu. The option to be used will be: Discontinue the use of the original hardware. Take the backup files from the old server, restore in the new server and proceed with the upgrade. In this case, no other operation (RemapDBs) should be used, correct? Only backup from the old server, restore on the new hardware, proceed with upgrade.

Comment: @L_C  Yes, Reconfigure server IDs and remap databases is used for clone option. Besides suggest you also [Refresh the data cache on client computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015#refresh-the-data-cache-on-client-computers)